# SMB share can't rename files/folders

Tags: macos, finder, permission, file-sharing, smb

On occasion cannot rename or delete files & folders on a Windows Server 2012 R2 SMB share from a Macbook.

Mac OS X 10.10 build 14A389a

The SMB share has granted "Everyone" with Full Control permissions.

Windows 7 desktops access the share without issue.

Error messages received are:

[image: The operation can't be completed. An unexpected error occurred (error code -8706).]

[image: You don't have permission to rename the item.]

Comment: Considering another TLA it is clear that the MBP is not seen it.

Comment: Windows 7 desktops access the share without issue. I believe the issue is with the Mac, not Windows.

Comment: agree, that is what I said MBP = MacBook Pro. Guessing the permissions are not clear on MBP site. Check Console log for errors on SMB.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is something we had issues with today at work.

It goes like this:

Have a folder (Folder 1) and create another folder in this folder (Folder 2). Copy a file (such as an image) into Folder 2. Now you won't be able to rename Folder 1 without Finder asking for admin password, and entering that gives the same dialog as the second posted above by Ash. Moving (or deleting) the file that was added to Folder 2 out  from that folder makes it possible to rename Folder 1 again. Seems like a bug to me. It has been reported to Apple.

Comment: I have just reconnected the Windows shares using CIFS:// instead of SMB:// for testing. Will provide an update here.

Comment: Issue has popped up again - asking for permission to move and rename files.

Answer (score 0):

Might have to do with the (automatically created) .DS_Store files.
I turned this function off and seems to be working proper now. Here's how:

http://support.apple.com/en-us/HT1629

Comment: What issues were you having prior to turning off .DS_Store files?

Answer (score 0):

Sounds like your having issues with ownership and permissions.
This might be due to storing user-X's file inside user-Y's directory.
Now when user-Y tries to rename his directory,
 he is in effect trying to alter the attributes of user-X's file.

---

Use the `stat` command to investigate.
Use `chown`, `chmod`, `chgrp`, & `chflags` to make any changes.